# The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android, xml

eclipse shows the "The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed” error while validating xml " error in the following code while building the project. help me guys!!

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.qriller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `<<<<<<< Original` and `>>>>>>> Added` from your code it will work